# Why is the Footer.svelte for my Portfolio Page not being rendered?

Tags: html, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, portfolio

The footer of the Website is not being rendered after deployment
UPDATED:
i have tried using vercel to see if was a git pages error but still the same issue persisted which leads me to believe i muse have missed something in the code

Here is a snippet of the `footer.svelte`

```
<footer class="py-20 sm:py-32 bg-black border-t border-solid border-violet-950 flex flex-col gap-4 sm:gap-8 justify-center items-center">
    <p class="px-4 py-2 bg-white text-slate-950 font-medium">Connect with me &darr;</p>
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-4 items-center justify-center">
        <p><b class="pr-2">Email</b> feranmioyelowo@gmail.com</p>
        <p>
            <b class="pr-2">GitHub</b>
            <a href="https://github.com/Oluwaferanmi-Dev" target="_blank" class="text-violet-400">
                Oluwaferanmi-Dev
                <sup class=""><span class="text-xs scale-75 pl-0.5"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square text-xs scale-[75%]"></i></span></sup>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b class="pr-2">LinkedIn</b>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/your-linkedin-profile" target="_blank" class="text-violet-400">
                your-linkedin-profile
                <sup class=""><span class="text-xs scale-75 pl-0.5"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up-right-from-square text-xs scale-[75%]"></i></span></sup>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

this is snippet of the `header.svelte` but this has no issues with it as it being rendered properly

```
<script>
    export let y;

    export let tabs = [
        { name: "Projects ", link: "#projects" },
        { name: "About me", link: "#about" },
        { name: "Blog", link: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" },
        
    ];
</script>

<header
    class={"sticky z-[10] top-0 duration-200 px-6 flex items-center justify-between border-b border-solid " +
        (y > 0
            ? " py-4 bg-slate-950 border-violet-950"
            : " py-6 bg-transparent border-transparent")}
>
    <h1 class="font-medium">
        <b class="font-bold poppins">Caleb </b> <span class="">Oyelowo</span>
    </h1>
    <div class="sm:flex ml-auto pr-4 items-center gap-4 hidden">
        {#each tabs as tab, index}
            <a
                href={tab.link}
                class="duration-200 hover:text-violet-400"
                target={index === 2 ? "_blank" : ""}
            >
                <p>{tab.name}</p>
            </a>
        {/each}
        
        <button
            class="blueShadow relative overflow-hidden px-5 py-2 group rounded-full bg-white text-slate-950"
        >
            <div
                class="absolute top-0 right-full w-full h-full bg-violet-400 opacity-20 group-hover:translate-x-full z-0 duration-200"
            />
            <h4 class="relative z-9">Get in touch</h4>
        </button>
    </div>
</header>
```

which leads me to the main.svelte

```
<script>
    import Step from "./Step.svelte";

    let steps = [
        {
            name: "Otakumart NG",
            icon: "fa-solid fa-cart-shopping",
            
        },
        {
            name: "Weather App",
            icon: "fa-solid fa-cloud",
            
        },
        {
            name: "The Gadget Hub",
            icon: "fa-solid fa-rocket",
           
        },
    ];

    let benefits = [
        {
            metric: "10x",
            name: "a self taught developer",
            description:
                "I taught myself to code using free online resources and absolutely fell in love with the creativity and problem solving that is involved in developing and engineering innovative new online experiences. Starting of with JavaScript, HTML & CSS and evolving my knowledge base to include JavaScript frameworks, backend programming, design, cloud services and much much more.",
        },
        {
            name: "a product design & UX finatic",
            description:
                "Carefully crafting and designing amazing user experiences allows me to express and experiment with every morsel of creativity I have. I love the challenge of learning new design concepts and enabling users with amazing online experiences.",
        },
        {
            name: "an excellent communicator",
            description:
                "Communication is key and it's a paramount value of mine. I believe in transparency and constructive communication above all else. This helps me develop deep relationships and ensures my effectiveness and productivity in any work space with any team.",
        },
    ];
</script>

<main class="flex flex-col flex-1 p-4">
    <section
        id="introPage"
        class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-10 py-8 sm:py-14"
    >
        <div
            class="flex flex-col lg:justify-center text-center lg:text-left gap-6 md:gap-8 lg:gap-10"
        >
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-4xl sm:text-5xl md:text-6xl">
                Hi! I'm <span class="poppins text-violet-400">Caleb</span> Oyelowo
                <br />Full Stack
                <span class="poppins text-violet-400">Developer</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="text-base sm:text-lg md:text-xl">
                My <span class="text-violet-400"> favorite tech</span> includes JavaScript
                (NEXT.JS or SvelteKit), TailwindCSS, Node.js + Express.js & PostgreSQL
                or Firebase/Firestore!
            </p>
            <button
                class="blueShadow mx-auto lg:mr-auto lg:ml-0 text-base sm:text-lg md:text-xl poppins relative overflow-hidden px-6 py-3 group rounded-full bg-white text-slate-950"
            >
                <div
                    class="absolute top-0 right-full w-full h-full bg-violet-400 opacity-20 group-hover:translate-x-full z-0 duration-200"
                />
                <h4 class="relative z-9">Get in touch &rarr;</h4>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="relative shadow-2xl grid place-items-center">
            <img
                src={"images/profile.png"}
                alt="Zetane Engine"
                class="object-cover z-[2] max-h-[70vh]"
            />
        </div>
      
    </section>
    <section class="py-20 lg:py-32 flex flex-col gap-24" id="projects">
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-2 text-center">
            <h6 class="text-large sm:text-xl md:text-2xl">
                A few of my creative endeavors.
            </h6>
            <h3 class="font-semibold text-3xl sm:text-4xl md:text-5xl">
                Curious to <span class="poppins text-violet-400">see</span> my work?
            </h3>
        </div>
        <a
            href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
            target="_blank"
            class="mx-auto px-4 py-2 rounded-md border border-solid border-white flex items-center gap-2 -mb-4 sm:-mb-0 -mt-10 hover:border-violet-700 duration-200"
        >
            <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-play" />
            <p>Watch the video</p>
        </a>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-12 lg:gap-10">
            <Step step={steps[0]}>
                <p>
                    Otakumart NG is merchandising store created with
                    <strong class="text-violet-400">Next.js, App Router, TypeScript, TailwindCSS, Prisma, DaisyUI </strong>, for otaku's
                     nationwide to shop from a catalougue of anime themed merchandise</p>
            </Step>

                    <Step step={steps[1]}>
                        <p>
                            Weather App is a mobile application made with <strong
                                class="text-violet-400">Native Wind, JavaScript</strong
                            >,
                            <strong class="text-violet-400">React Native</strong
                            >
                            & <strong class="text-violet-400">Expo</strong>, It provides users with real-time weather updates, forecasts, and weather alerts.
                    </Step>
                    <Step step={steps[2]}>
                        <p>
                            Chat Me is a <strong class="text-violet-400"
                                >React & Node.js</strong
                            >
                            web application that facilitates efficient communication and collaboration within companies. 
                            It enables real-time messaging, helping teams coordinate tasks and share updates seamlessly with the help of
                            <strong class="text-violet-400">Firebase</strong>
                           
                </p>
            </Step>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section
        id="about"
        class="py-20 pt-10 lg:pt-16 lg:py-32 flex flex-col gap-16 sm:gap-20 md:gap-24 relative"
    >
       
        <div
            class="flex flex-col gap-2 text-center relative before:absolute before:top-0 before:left-0 before:w-2/3 before:h-1.5 before:bg-violet-700 after:absolute after:bottom-0 after:right-0 after:w-2/3 after:h-1.5 after:bg-violet-700 py-4"
        >
            <h6 class="text-large sm:text-xl md:text-2xl">
                Want to know more?
            </h6>
            <h3 class="font-semibold text-3xl sm:text-4xl md:text-5xl">
                A bit <span class="poppins text-violet-400">about</span> me.
            </h3>
        </div>
        <p class="mx-auto poppins font-semibold text-lg sm:text-xl md:text-2xl">
            I am . . .
        </p>
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-20 w-full mx-auto max-w-[800px]">
            {#each benefits as benefit, index}
                
                <div class="flex gap-6 sm:gap-8">
                    <p
                        class="poppins text-4xl sm:text-5xl md:text-6xl text-slate-500 font-semibold"
                    >
                        0{index + 1}
                    </p>
                    <div class="flex flex-col gap-6 sm:gap-8">
                        <h3 class="text-2xl sm:text-3xl md:text-5xl">
                            {benefit.name}
                        </h3>
                        <p>{benefit.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/each}
        </div>
        <h5 class={" text-2xl sm:text-3xl font-semibold text-center poppins "}>
            The <span class="text-violet-400">Complete</span> Package
        </h5>
        <div
            class="flex flex-col overflow-x-scroll gap-10 max-w-[800px] mx-auto w-full"
        >
            <table class="bg-white text-slate-700 rounded text-center">
                <thead class={"border-b border-solid border-slate-200  "}>
                    <tr class="">
                        <th />
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap p-2 px-4">Candidate #1</th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap p-2 px-4">Candidate #2</th>
                        <th class="whitespace-nowrap p-2 px-4">Candidate #3</th>
                        <th
                            class="bg-violet-700 text-white whitespace-nowrap p-4 px-8"
                            >Me</th
                        >
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="border-b border-solid border-slate-200">
                        <td
                            class="border-r border-solid border-white pl-4 pr-8 py-4 font-semibold text-sm"
                            >Dedication</td
                        >
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-green-500" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="border-b border-solid border-slate-200">
                        <td
                            class="border-r border-solid border-white pl-4 pr-8 py-4 font-semibold text-sm"
                            >Critical Thought</td
                        >
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-green-500" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td
                            class="border-r border-solid border-white pl-4 pr-8 py-4 font-semibold text-sm"
                            >Interpersonal Skills</td
                        >
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-green-500" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="border-t border-solid border-slate-200">
                        <td
                            class="border-r border-solid border-white pl-4 pr-8 py-4 font-semibold text-sm"
                            >Progamming Ability</td
                        >
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-slate-500" /></td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check text-green-500" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto -mt-12 italic sm:hidden opacity-50">
            <p>Scroll to see more &rarr;</p>
        </div>
        <p class="mx-auto">So why not invest?</p>
    </section>
</main>
```

I have tried debugging to the best of my knowledge and have still not been able to find the root cause, this might be because it's my first time working with svelte rather than the normal html format where the footer is rendered inside the main rather than a separate footer.svelte

Comment: All relevant code should be part of the questions, do not just link somewhere else. Create a minimal example first to reduce code. Also specify clearly where you deploy to and how.

Comment: If this is about GitHub Pages, there already are already [multiple questions on using SvelteKit for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-pages+sveltekit).

Comment: As I said, please create a **minimal** example. Most of this code is probably completely irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Kindly share a URL for your deployment on vercel? Also, are you using Svelte or SvelteKit?

Answer (score 1):

By convention components in Svelte should be camelcase (footer.svelte -> Footer.svelte).

also, **you don't seem to have imported your component** in the main.svelte.

You have properly imported **Step.svelte** for example.

`import Step from "./Step.svelte";`

Which you can then use doing so :
`<Step></Step>`